# Dynamic input checkbox ids

Tags: forms, vuejs2

I generate input type=checkboxes dynamically. ie. have them in my template.
These might come one hundred and problem is that the label requires for=“id-name” and I don't know how to give that same name as the input has

```
<input type=“checkbox” name=“special” v-bind:id="‘mynew’ + special.id />
<label v-bind:for="‘mynew’" + special.id">
```

obviously v-bind:for does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to keep the value of your input by making a model for it like:

```
<input v-model="message" ... /> 

<script> 
export default {
 data: {
  return {
    message: ''
  }
 }
}
```

Then you can use the model inside your `for=""` attribute as:

```
<label v-bind:for="'id+name' + message">
```

Comment: I must try this. I get back.

Comment: Thanks. You made me realize I  only had a typo. But had to do it in a different manner. It is a checkbox. Value is either checked or not checked. I'm nit sure about message

Comment: np .. make sure to accept this answer if it solved your question

Comment: sure I can accept it but it did not explain my fault, nor do I need the message

Comment: You need the message, so you can bind it to the label afterwards. without the message, you won't get the input value

Comment: but i have one hundred of them. where will this message be stored

Comment: then you have to create an array of message and use v-for loop to loop over the input and the label together, so you can easily pass the message to both elements